# Static objects for shared *.so files

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

In C++ project, we have the following dependency:

1. Package1.so - shared lib/functional having **std::shared_ptr<T*> getInstance()** static function which returns a static shared pointer. If the static pointer isn't initialized, it initializes then returns the pointer. It also uses static mutex to guarantee sync in case of MT mode call to getInstance
2. Package2, which depends on Package1.so and uses the getInstance function to fetch data
3. Package3, has dependency from Package1 and Package2 and also directly uses 'getInstance' function

It's expected that static object should be created only once and be shared between package 2& 3

However, seems the shared object is different for Package2 & 3 -> the object is created twice.

Question: Is static memory space is not shared in case of .so files?

```
// Package 1
// h1.hpp
#pragma once

class A {
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<A> get_instance();
  
 private:
  static std::mutex m_mtx;
  static std::shared_ptr<A> m_instance;
};

// Package 1
// h1.cpp
static std::mutex A::m_mtx;
static std::shared_ptr<A> A::m_instance;

std::shared_ptr<A> A::get_instance() {
  const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck{m_mtx);
  if (nullptr == m_instance) {
     m_instance = std::make_shared<A>();
  }
  return m_instance;
}


// Package 2 depending Package 1
#include <path/h1.hpp>

void f() {
   auto instance = A::get_instance(); // for first call creates new
}


// Package 3 depending Package 1 and Package 2
#include <path/h1.hpp>
void g() {
   auto instance = A::get_instance(); // for first call creates new
}



// Result - 2 instances are created of A - one thought Package 3 one through Package 2
```

// Expected - a single A should be created and static shared ptr should be shared.

Comment: If they were shared, that would mean they had to be made aware of each others existence. This is not the case. Package1 needs to be wrapped by some service. Or your project needs to reuse the result from P1::getInstance().

Comment: Please show an actual [mre] for your issue. There are unclear details here. For example why "_static function_"? If the function is `static`, then each translation unit has its own independent copy. Also "_It also uses static mutex to guarantee sync_" is redundant. Since C++11 this is already implicitly guaranteed by the language for the initializer of a local static variable.

Comment: "_Question: Is static memory space is not shared in case of .so files?_": It is shared, assuming that the relevant entities have external linkage and you are not using any non-standard mechanism to invert this behavior. Something is probably wrong in your code.

Comment: What compiler did you use to test the code you are showing now? It should not compile.

Comment: What does "seems the shared object is different" mean? What led you to believe that "the object is created twice"? What happens if you get rid of both the unnecessary `m_mutex` and `m_instance`, then simply change `get_instance()` to `std::shared_ptr<A> A::get_instance() {
  static auto m_instance=std::make_shared<A>();
  return m_instance;
}`?

Comment: 1. I know this is unusual problem and can be related with use of incorrect config in CMakeList(like Package1:Shared vs Package1:Static).

Comment: 'std::shared_ptr<A> A::get_instance() { static auto m_instance=std::make_shared<A>(); return m_instance; }'. - this is not thread safe function @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @MartinAyvazyan It is thread-safe. (Assuming you didn't tell the compiler to deviate from the standard's behavior with a compiler flag.) (Safe since C++11, which you must be using for `std::shared_ptr` anyway.)

Comment: You are mistaken, it is thread-safe. The C++ standard requires synchronization of static-scoped local function objects.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it's only since C++11 only.

Comment: btw, the main problem of this item is shared objects behavior between 2 packages.

Comment: Your problem is still not reproducible because the code you are showing doesn't even compile (even after adding missing `#include`s, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

The shared pointers themselves are different because they are different objects but they point to the same underlying object. This is by design.

I took your example and reran it, it produces the following.

```bash
$ ./main
Instance:0x7fb7001a00a0 Object:0x55ae9c53aec0
Instance:0x7fb70019b0a0 Object:0x55ae9c53aec0
```

I created a main.cpp that calls `f` and `g`

```cpp
void f();
void g();

int main() {
        f();
        g();
}
```

`f.cpp` is in a different library `libf.so`. I assign it to a static object otherwise calling `f()` and `g()` could print the same address for same objects just by coincidence.

```cpp
#include "h1.h"
void f() {
   static auto instance = A::get_instance(); // for first call creates new
   printf( "Instance:%p Object:%p\n", &instance, instance.get() );
}
```

Same thing for `g.cpp`

```cpp
#include "h1.h"
void g() {
   static auto instance = A::get_instance(); // for first call creates new
   printf( "Instance:%p Object:%p\n", &instance, instance.get() );
}
```

Notice that on `h1.h` you are returning a copy of the static variable, not a reference to it. That is okay but it will generate a copy and perhaps that's not what you expect.

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

class A {
public:
  static std::shared_ptr<A> get_instance();
private:
  static std::mutex m_mtx;
  static std::shared_ptr<A> m_instance;
};
```

On this file `h1.cpp` you had the keyword `static` prefixed to the implementation of the two variables. That is a bug and I commented out. It should not compile. Maybe that is the reason for your problem.

```cpp
#include "h1.h"

/* static */  std::mutex A::m_mtx;
/* static */  std::shared_ptr<A> A::m_instance;

std::shared_ptr<A> A::get_instance() {
  const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck{m_mtx};
  if (nullptr == m_instance) {
     m_instance = std::make_shared<A>();
  }
  return m_instance;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )
project(deps)

add_library( h1 SHARED h1.cpp )

add_library( f SHARED f.cpp )
target_link_libraries( f h1 )

add_library( g SHARED g.cpp )
target_link_libraries( g h1 )

add_executable( main main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( main h1 f g )
```